# Export-Csv and Array objects

Tags: powershell-6.0

I have a CSV that I want to process in an array object and export as another CSV. However when I do that, instead of copying the values of the array, it copies the attribute of the object.

```
"Length","LongLength","Rank","SyncRoot","IsReadOnly","IsFixedSize","IsSynchronized","Count"
"52","52","1","System.Object[]","False","True","False","52"
```

How can resolve this?

**EDIT**:

The code that caused this:

```
Export-Csv $data test.csv
```

Where `$data` is the array that stores the output of the import-csv.

Comment: Please show the code that produced this output as well as the corresponding sample input. Generally speaking, `Export-Csv` expects a list/array of objects as input and converts the properties of those objects to the fields of the CSV, taking the property names of the first object as the column header.

Comment: `Export-Csv $data test.csv` -> `$data | Export-Csv test.csv`

Comment: Thank you, this was very much helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `-InputObject` became a positional parameter in PowerShell v6, otherwise the code you posted should've thrown an error

> Export-Csv : Cannot bind parameter 'Delimiter'. Cannot convert value "test.csv" to type "System.Char". Error: "String must be exactly one character long."

Anyway, the code you posted is effectifly running

```
Export-Csv -InputObject $data -Path test.csv
```

However, the parameter `-InputObject` takes a single PSObject argument, not an array of PSObjects. If you pass it an array, the CSV output is created from that array object, not from the elements of the array.

Pipe the array to `Export-Csv` to have the output created from the array elements:

```
$data | Export-Csv -Path test.csv -NoType
```